# What is the Max capability of Databricks memory?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

1st lets have a look my cluster configuration.

Worker Type: Standard_D3_V2 (14GB Memory,4Cores,0.75 DBU)

and I have 35 worker so total is

35 Workers: 490.0 GB Memory, 140 Cores, 26.25 DBU

1 Driver: 14.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 0.75 DBU
[image]

So my total memory is **14*36=504GB**
But when I run job,Code etc in this cluster and in Spark UI it seems my Total Memory is **320GB** not **504GB**
[image]

My question is why its not showing total memory? I am not saying why it is not using total memory,
What I am saying my total memory is **504GB** but its show Total=**320GB**, where is others **184GB** goes?

Comment: Considering that the bottom-left diagram visually displays "Swap" memory as beyond the red line denoting "Total" memory, perhaps 320GB corresponds to physical memory (RAM) whereas 504GB corresponds to virtual memory (memory-addressable space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total memory is divided into the physical memory and virtual memory.

You have selected total memory (**14 x 36 = 504 G**) divided into **320** physical memory and **184** as the virtual memory.

To get more details on the total memory, go to **Live Metrics** => **Ganglia UI** => click on the **Physical View** and Select the a **Node** and check out the available memory for each node after setup up the VM.

[image]

**Note:** `Available memory = (Available memory from physical view) x (Number of Nodes)`

[image]

> To understand difference between Physical storage and virtual Address
>   space, you may go through the below details:

The virtual address space of each process can be smaller or larger than the total physical memory available on the VM. The subset of the virtual address space of a process that resides in physical memory is known as the working set. If the threads of a process attempt to use more physical memory than is currently available, the system pages some of the memory contents to disk. The total amount of virtual address space available to a process is limited by physical memory and the free space on disk available for the paging file.

Physical storage and the virtual address space of each process are organized into pages, units of memory, whose size depends on the VM selected.

To maximize its flexibility in managing memory, the system can move pages of physical memory to and from a paging file on disk. When a page is moved in physical memory, the system updates the page maps of the affected processes. When the system needs space in physical memory, it moves the least recently used pages of physical memory to the paging file. Manipulation of physical memory by the system is completely transparent to applications, which operate only in their virtual address spaces.

Hope this helps.